# Java and netbeans, deploying project troubles

Tags: netbeans

netbeans 20, windows 10.

I have written a program which runs fine when i use run -> run main project. Iam looking to have this program run standalone outside of the IDE on my system and other systems.

After following tutorials online:

setting Main class in properties - done

and

clean and build

**my java folder does not contain the "build" or "dist" files** like everyone says it should
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cofPw.png)

it does however have the projectname.jar in the target folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsTx0.png)

not sure if this is the same? as when i click it the command prompt quickly appears but nothing else happens, i was expecting it to run at this point, yes java is installed.

Am i missing something obvious here? is my POM causing issue?

(other properties settings that might be of interest:

source binary format: 1.8,
java script libraries not showing any options,
build/compile JDK 17)

had "bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8"
show in console when clean and build.

here is the output dialog when i clean and build

cd C:\Users\james\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataTable; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17" cmd /c ""C:\Program Files\NetBeans-20\netbeans\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\NetBeans-20\netbeans\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" --no-transfer-progress clean install"
Scanning for projects...

--------------------< com.mycompany:FreightTracker >--------------------
Building FreightTracker 1.0
from pom.xml
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ FreightTracker ---
Deleting C:\Users\james\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataTable\target

--- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ FreightTracker ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\james\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataTable\src\main\resources

--- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ FreightTracker ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
Compiling 3 source files with javac [debug target 1.8] to target\classes
bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8

--- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ FreightTracker ---
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\james\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataTable\src\test\resources

--- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ FreightTracker ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency

--- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test) @ FreightTracker ---

--- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ FreightTracker ---
Building jar: C:\Users\james\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataTable\target\FreightTracker-1.0.jar

--- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ FreightTracker ---
Installing C:\Users\james\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataTable\pom.xml to C:\Users\james.m2\repository\com\mycompany\FreightTracker\1.0\FreightTracker-1.0.pom
Installing C:\Users\james\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DataTable\target\FreightTracker-1.0.jar to C:\Users\james.m2\repository\com\mycompany\FreightTracker\1.0\FreightTracker-1.0.jar

BUILD SUCCESS

Assuming "clean and build" would create a dist file in my project directory, it is not there, but a file appears in "target" folder, when i click nothing happens - expecting file to run outside of IDE...

Comment: The simple and quick answer is that to execute your JAR file (if it is an executable JAR), you just need to enter the following command in the command line: java -jar xxx.jar (where xxx.jar is the name of your JAR file). 
As a reference, you need to provide at least the content of your pom.xml file.

Comment: 1. Utilizing the maven-assembly-plugin can assist in packaging your project into a directory. It provides relevant startup scripts and encapsulates other dependent JARs.
2. After the packaging process is complete, you can use the launch4j-maven-plugin to package the entire directory and convert it into an executable (exe) file.
3. A more advanced approach involves using the JDK's bundled tool, jpackage, to package your program into an MSI file. This MSI file allows users to install the application without requiring them to pre-install the JDK or JRE.